# java.security.NoSuchProviderException: no such provider: SUN

Tags: java, websphere, google-authenticator

I have implemented two factor authentication with QR code. I've done it using [GoogleAuth](https://github.com/wstrange/GoogleAuth) library. In my local environment works like a charm but when I deploy the application on WebSphere 8.5.5 it throws this error:

```
java.security.NoSuchProviderException: no such provider: SUN
```

And `GoogleAuth` throw this exception:

```
Could not initialise SecureRandom with the specified provider: SUN. 
Another provider can be chosen setting the com.warrenstrange.googleauth.rng.algorithmProvider system property
```

on this method:

```
private String getRandomNumberAlgorithm()
{
    return System.getProperty(RNG_ALGORITHM, DEFAULT_RANDOM_NUMBER_ALGORITHM);
}
```

I found this [issue](https://github.com/wstrange/GoogleAuth/issues/26) on project's GitHub page that is very similar to my problem and here the guy who wrote this library explaines what this method does:

> The library currently gets a SecureRandom instance using the
>   SecureRandom#getInstance method and specifying the SHA1PRNG algorithm
>   and the SUN provider

I understood that I have to override `SUN` provider with another one using `System.setProperty("com.warrenstrange.googleauth.rng.algorithmProvider", "property")`, because the system can't find it, but I don't understand why is throwing the exception.
On my machine I run the application with Java 7 and Websphere uses the same version. The difference is the application that runs on WebSphere is compiled with Java 6.

My questions are:

Why is throwing this exception? Isn't `SUN` provider part of Java?

What other provider should I use and how?

Comment: The difference is that SUN provider is not available by default in some WebSphere/Java versions. You can check, if it is present in the `java.security` file in `WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/security` directory.  Specify `IBMJCE` as provider via that property to use it instead of `SUN`.

Comment: @Gas Thank you so much, you were totally right there was no `SUN` provider in `java.security` file. I set `IBMJCE` as provider and it worked. If you want to write an answer I will be really glad to give you the reputation you deserve. Thanks again!

Comment: In my case I just changed from SUN to IBMJCE and it worked too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that `SUN` provider is not available by default in some WebSphere/Java versions. You can check, if it is present in the `java.security` file in `WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/security` directory.

Specify `IBMJCE` as provider via that property to use it instead of `SUN`

Comment: I am facing this issue right now in my websphere application. How to set IBMJCE as provider? Can you please give me that command?

Comment: @PoonkodiSivapragasam it depends on the API you are using. If you use that Google then the command is `System.setProperty("com.warrenstrange.googleauth.rng.algorithmProvider", "IBMJCE");`